# Lift the FB pin of buck regulator

Tags: buck

I have a basic buck regulator with feedback control. \
If I open feedback pin of the regulator (example lift the FB pin), then the regulator will be damaged. Why ?

Regards,
Azlum

Comment: What do you mean "lift"? Disconnect? In this case the regulator will not regulate (because the setpoint is controlled by the FB pin, which would be floating), and assuming that FB is pulled to ground, the output voltage will rise to the input (they will be shorted together). I am not sure that this will necessarily damage the regulator, but it could do. If there is no pull up or pull down for FB then the regulator will behave unpredictably.

Comment: Why are you floating the feedback pin in the first place?

Comment: @OleksandrR., if the input voltage is high and the load impedance is low, it could *definitely* damage the regulator (and probably the load too).

Comment: @DanLaks well, yes, we can certainly construe a scenario whereby the converter is damaged. But I think there is nothing that requires it to be damaged if FB is not connected; rather it will just not do anything useful. A reference to a specific regulator would be helpful, of course.

Comment: @OleksandrR. wasn't trying to challenge what you wrote, but was actually reinforcing your point. We need more information from the OP about the circuit and why he's doing what he's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the regulator will be damaged depends on a number of factors related to the specific  application, but:

If the feedback loop is broken 3 things can happen.

- The feedback input to the error amplifier falls to ground or low potential. 
  The converter goes to maximum voltage out as it "tries" to cause the feedback pin to rise.
  Vout = Vmax
- The feedback input to the error amplifier is pulled high.
  The converter goes to minimum voltage (usually ground) out as it "tries" to cause the feedback pin to fall.
  Vout = zero
- The feedback input to the error amplifier floats and varies randomly.
  The regulator output tends to transition to or towards Vmax when FB pin is less than FB set point and to or towards ground when FB pin is above FB set point.
  Vout = "interesting"

If Vout goes to Vmax a connected load may draw too much current or be destroyed.  This may lead to excessive output and input current which, depending on the design, may or may not damage the  regulator.

Comment: Hello All, I just floated the FB pin (not connected to pulled-up, pulled-low, or not connected to output). If FB pin is low, then the regulator trying to generate max output and which case damage. Is it like that ?

Comment: @MohammedAzlum You have to read the answer. What you are asking now is in the answer already. And read what I said about damage.